# Getting name attribute of an object

Tags: jquery

I set up a function that gets the name attribute of an object and runs a function. The name of the object is set up as a variable but it's not working when I called it. What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/wPUhK/1/

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your call to `parent()` is only getting you the `<p>` containing the link, not the element you want. Either add a second `.parent()`, or use a more suitable function for finding a specific container.

Second, your selector should be: `$('[name='+completed+']')`